# Firebase query get today's bookings pass back into array

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to get all the bookings returned from firebase that match todays date.

I am using an *ngFor order of orders in my html to print out all returned orders.

In the firebase database I have 7 bookings saved. 2 out of the 7 are todays date. so all 7 are printing out on screen ok. However when I click my button to run the following function I want to display only bookings for todays date.

```
todayBookings() {

    this.ordersData = this.af.list('/orders', {

        query: {
            orderByChild: 'start',
            // equalTo: today
        }
    });
    this.ordersData.subscribe((res) => {
        this.orders = res;
    });

    this.orders.forEach(order => {

        var d = new Date();
        var curr_date = ("0" + (d.getDate() + 0)).slice(-2);
        var curr_month = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
        var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
        // get today's date
        var today = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
        // get date of booking
        var dateOfBooking = order.start.substr(0, 10);

        if (dateOfBooking == today) {
            this.todaysOrders = order;
            var index = this.orders.indexOf(order, 0);
            if (index > -1) {
                this.orders.splice(index, 1);
            }
            // console.log(this.orders);
            // console.log(this.todaysOrders);

        }

    });

    this.orders = this.todaysOrders
    console.log(this.orders);
}
```

When I console log the following: console.log(this.todaysOrders);

I see in the console the 2 bookings for today:

[image: screenshot of console]

Unfortunately I don't know how to now take this.todaysOrders and pass them back into this.orders.

I tried the following:

this.orders.push(this.todaysOrders);

But it brought back all entries and appended the todays bookings to the list so instead of 7 entries returned it brought 9. (all bookings + the 2 bookings with todays date).

Orders in database

```
orders
 -Ko2a0zwYPQc-ocfJ1cF
   createdAt: 1499003887000
   orderId: 34681
   partySize: "1"
   requirements: "none"
   start: "2017-07-02T15:00:44+01:00"
   status: "Accepted"
   type: "tablebooking"
   + userDetails
   userId: "CQbDG6H8ENStlZiaNOGNsvbw2GL2"

   -Ko2ay19E7b17UhZ9HAf
   -Ko2pmavUZNTKdsr0pv6
   -Ko2t6cm35uOtiROeghG
   -Ko2tn6iRmkG7Y-OfAcJ
   -Ko2u5FrD5ZnIphL9Vno
   -KoBtilv2-dj-XmQSQBf
```

Here is the whole class. I have stripped out other functions I am using for other things on the page.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnDestroy, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { ToastrService } from 'toastr-ng2';
import * as moment from 'moment';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-calendar',
    templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss']
})

export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges {



    order: Array<any>;
    orders: Array<any>;
    ordersData: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

    todaysOrders: Array<any>;

    color: any;
    orderId: any;


    @ViewChild('fullcalendar') fullcalendar: ElementRef;


    constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase, public toastr: ToastrService, public router: Router, public authentication: AngularFireAuth) {


        this.ordersData = af.list('/orders', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'start',
            }
        });
        this.ordersData.subscribe((res) => {
            this.orders = res;
        });


    }




    //Get Todays Bookings
    todayBookings() {

        this.ordersData = this.af.list('/orders', {

            query: {
                orderByChild: 'start',
                // equalTo: today
            }
        });
        this.ordersData.subscribe((res) => {
            this.orders = res;
        });

        this.orders.forEach(order => {

            var d = new Date();
            var curr_date = ("0" + (d.getDate() + 0)).slice(-2);
            var curr_month = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
            var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
            // get today's date
            var today = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
            // get date of booking
            var dateOfBooking = order.start.substr(0, 10);

            if (dateOfBooking == today) {
                this.todaysOrders = order;
                var index = this.orders.indexOf(order, 0);
                if (index > -1) {
                    this.orders.splice(index, 1);
                }
                // console.log(this.orders);
                console.log(this.todaysOrders);

            }

        });

        // this.orders = this.todaysOrders
        // console.log(this.orders);
    }





}
```

Comment: My database is firebase not sure what you mean buddy

Comment: Show us what is in your database, the layout/structure

Comment: Updated main post :)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete each order of today from the `orders` array.

something like :

```
if (dateOfBooking == today) {
  this.todaysOrders = order;
  var index = this.orders.indexOf(order, 0);
  if (index > -1) {
    this.orders.splice(index, 1);
  }
  console.log(this.todaysOrders);
  console.log(this.orders);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion @Lilrom however, in the console I see this removes todays orders, I don't want to remove them, this is the orders I need to show, I want to remove all orders that are not today's date.

Comment: Maybe something like `this.orders =  this.todaysOrders`  after your `forEach` ?

Comment: That did not work also i'm afraid. When I console.log(this.orders) I get an array of objects back that are not todays booking. when I console.log(this.todaysOrders) I get back todays orders but as individual objects not an array of objects which I need. I also added this.orders = this.todaysOrders after the foreach but I get an error in the console: **Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed** I have updated my question with your additional code.

Comment: I found this useful doc https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md did you read it ? Can you please share all your class ?

Comment: Added full class to main post. Thank you for the link also, it has excellent information which I will certainly make use of.